# Need a faster Excel interop method

Tags: .net, com, excel-interop

It appears to be common knowledge that interop with Excel and .Net is very slow.  I'm aware of the ability to copy an array of values to a worksheet object in one go, but according to my stopwatch even one command (inside VB.Net) of the type:

```
 WS.Range(--range string here--).Value = array
```

...takes over 0.3 s! This adds up since my routine writes dozens of arrays to each worksheet, and there are several worksheets per workbook, and I'll probably be iterating through several workbooks as well.

If there was a way to write discontinuous, non-rectangular groups of cells at once, then I could do an entire WS with one write command.  But I don't think there's a way to do that while preserving original values for the "inbetween" cells.  These workbooks are pre-formatted so I have to leave particular cells as is.

Anything I can do to speed this up?

Comment: Have you tried turning off calculation, then turning it back on again at the end? Remember to do a recalc all. Also, try doing it from VBA - if it is still slow then .Net is not to blame.

Comment: Thanks, that actually made a big difference. I was aware of this practice, but didn't think that calculation was that big a hit (for these worksheets anyways). Just assumed the bottleneck was .Net-Com interop.  Not sure how to give the Answer to a comment, so guess I'll just post one myself.

Comment: You could also ask Ben to post an Answer, so you could accept it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben's comment above pretty much nailed it; excel's formula calculations were the bottleneck.  I'm relieved, because I knew .Net-Excel interop had a reputation for being slow, but didn't think it was *that* slow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if this is possible but you look into a library which does the same thing: [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). It can read and write from/to Excel documents.
Using this made my application a lot faster (getting data from xls into C# app)